# classcast exception with grails 2.2.3 and spock 0.7

Tags: grails, spock

The following is what we are doing and it worked in grails 2.0.0 and spock 0.6

A Simple Domain:

```
package com.grails
class User {
    String name, password
    def methodWithNoArguments(){
        return "Object: methodWithNoArguments"
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Unit spec:

```
package com.grails

import spock.lang.* 
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor 
import grails.test.mixin.Mock 
import grails.test.GrailsMock

@TestFor(UserController)  // testing for 
@Mock([User])             // collaborators class 
UserControllerSpec extends  Specification {
    // DOES NOT work in 2.2.3 spock 0.7,
    // WORKS in grails-2.0.0 spock 0.6
    def 'create a Domain collaborator using Mock'() {
        given: 'user'
        // can't mock this anymore, causes classcast exception.
        User user = Mock(User)

        user.methodWithNoArguments()  >> { "Mock: (3) methodWithNoArguments" }

        when: 'we call the method'
        def val1 = user.methodWithNoArguments()

        then: 'value should be from the mocked method'
        val1 == "Mock: (3) methodWithNoArguments"
    } }
```

the above causes the following exception in grails 2.2.3 and spock 0.7.  NOTE ( it works in grails-2.0.0 and spock 0.6 )

|  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.grails.User cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory
        at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:93)
        at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
        at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
        at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
        at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:47)
        at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:282)
        at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:99)
        at com.grails.UserControllerSpec.create a Domain collaborator using Mock(UserControllerSpec.groovy:94)

wondering if there could be some incompatible libraries, here is the BuildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    test(":spock:0.7") {
        exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }
}
```

sample test app is located at git@github.com:nbostech/grails-spock-2.2.3.git

git checkout grails-2.0.0; <2.0.0>/bin/grails test-app --unit UserControllerSpec; // all the tests pass

git checkout master; <2.2.3>/bin/grails test-app --unit UserControllerSpec; // one of the test fails..

Answer (score 2):

Grails and Spock mocks aren't intended to be mixed in this way. Either make it a Grails `@Mock`, or a Spock `Mock()`.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  what is the recommended approach, `@Mock` or Spock Mock()?

is it possible to use Spock Mock() and get all the Gorm methods?

or if we use `@Mock` which gives all the Gorm methods and have a nice convenience of stubbing out methods and verifying like..

    given: 
      User object = new User()  // uses Grails @Mock

      object.method(_) >> { }   // how can I get these to work??
      object.another( "x" ) >> { }
    then: 
      2 * object.method(_)
      3 * object.another("x")

Comment: It's a case-by-case decision. Grails mocks and Spock mocks are entirely different beasts, and to my knowledge it isn't possible to combine their features.

Comment: tried some integration specs as well, using Spock Mock() in a simple integration spec in isolation is causing the same exception. see the sample code on https://github.com/nbostech/grails-spock-2.2.3.. all the test cases pass in grails-2.0.0 and spock 0.6 ..

Comment: So what you are saying is that when you do `@Mock(User)` in one test method, you cannot do `Mock(User)` in another test method? Or not even in another test class?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  once @Mock(User) is used in a testclass any subsequent testclasses using the Mock(User) is throwing an exception..

Comment: Sounds like a bug/limitation in the latest Grails version. I recommend to take this to the Grails mailing list.

Comment: that sure sounds like a bug in Grails, JIRA: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10217